# Permuting elements within a list

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation, order

I have

```
s = {2, 3, 5, 7, 1, 4, 6}  (* always with diffente elements in {1,2....7}*)
l = Length[s]
n = 3
```

and `n` tells us that we want to select 3 positions in the list `s`, and permute them within the full list.

For example,

```
a = RandomSample[Range[l], n]
```

Suppose we obtain `a = {2, 6, 4}` and we apply a random permutation to these positions obtaining `{4, 6, 2}`. Then

Position 2 goes to position 4
Position 6 goes to position 6
Position 4 goes to position 2

obtaining

```
s = {2, 7, 5, 3, 1, 4, 6}
```

What´s a simple (and comprehensible) way without using an auxiliary list.

#### Edit

After reading MrWizard an Yi-Wang answers: (I like the `s[[a]] =s[[b]]` of MWizard, and the use of permutations and rule of Yi-Wang, but I think that a simpler an more comprehensible way is

```
s = {2, 3, 5, 7, 1, 4, 6}
n = 3
Print["BEFORE -> ", s]
choice = RandomSample[Range[Length[s]], n]
choicepermuted = RandomSample[choice, n]
s[[choice]] = s[[choicepermuted]]
Print["AFTER ->  ", s]
```

Comment: Why without without use an auxiliary list?  Is modification of the original list acceptable?

Comment: Pardon me, but you seem to have added my method to your question, stated you like it best, but given the Accept (green tickmark) to Yi Wang.  This confounds me.  Why?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Yes, I like your code     s[[a]] = s[[b]] for the interchange but "a" is not a random selection os positions, and "b" is not a Permutation of previous selection. And the solution of Yi-wang does exactly what I wanted. This is the issue because I invite you to edit your answer to give a randomly and b an randomly permutation of a. But.... YES Youre righth the f2 function you propose is perfect. I change now the green tickmark :-) It´s a pity that is no possible give TWO ACCEPTS :-) because many of you are very very good, and it´s a trouble having to choose :-))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the simplest and probably also fasted method.  If it is not acceptable please explain why.

```
s = {2, 3, 5, 7, 1, 4, 6};

a = {2, 6, 4};  (* random sample *)
b = {4, 6, 2};  (* permuted *)

s[[a]] = s[[b]];

s
```

> ```
> {2, 7, 5, 3, 1, 4, 6}
> ```

You can always make a copy of the list if you don't want to modify the original, e.g. `s2 = s`, then operate on `s2`.

---

Full code for clarity.  A function for in-place modification:

```
SetAttributes[f1, HoldFirst]

f1[s_Symbol?VectorQ, n_Integer] :=
  (s[[#]] = s[[ RandomSample @ # ]];) & @ RandomSample[Range @ Length @ s, n]
```

(You must evaluate `s` to see the result.)

And one for modification of a copy:

```
f2[ss_List, n_Integer] :=
  Module[{a, s = ss},
    a = RandomSample[Range @ Length @ s, n];
    s[[a]] = s[[ RandomSample @ a ]];
    s
  ]
```

Comment: @mr-wizard is perfect, the only aspect is use Random for a, and after, use random for  make b= permutation of b, if you want to edit to other people.

Comment: @MikaIke Thanks for the Accept.  Do I understand that you are suggesting I include the actual `RandomSample` usage in this answer, for clarity?

Comment: @mr-wizars, your me is enough! :-) but... in that example you set the positions will be permuted a = {2, 6, 4};  but if you want randomly select 3 positions, it´s suitable use the Random for the position and for the permutation (b)

Comment: @MikaIke See update.

Comment: @mr-wizard Thank you very much. I like it, and learn with your answers, but in this case I think that it´s very complicated for what I want. I edited the original quesiton with a little of you, and a little of Yi-Wang answers :-)

Comment: @MikaIke Rather than being complicated I hoped that the functions I included would show you how to make this method easy to (re)apply without unnecessary retyping.  Of course you could do it as shown in your modified question; that it what I intended in the first part of my answer, but I used the specific values for `a` and `b` that you gave, so that the operation would be clear.

Answer (score 2):

I think Mr. Wizard's way is cleaner. Nevertheless, here is another approach: One can select the numbers to permute first, and then permute them and replace them.

```
s = {2, 3, 5, 7, 1, 4, 6};
n = 3;

choice = RandomSample[s, n];
choicePermuted = Permute[choice, RandomPermutation[3]];
rule = Dispatch @ MapThread[Rule, {choice, choicePermuted}];

s /. rule
```

Comment: Thank you. Perfect! I don´t know use the rules. I must learn.

Comment: On short lists this should be adequate.  Be aware that on long lists it will become quite inefficient, though adding `Dispatch` may help.

Comment: @yi-wang Excuse me, Your answer is a good solution for me (especially if i want to store the permutation applied), but the MrQizard option is less simple, and is valid for me.

Comment: BTW, I made a modification: `choice = RandomSample[Range@l, n]` is changed to `choice = RandomSample[s, n]`. Although for the particular `s` it doesn't make a difference, I think the new version is what the OP really wants.

Comment: @yi-wang I like very much your answer, because show the permutation if you want. but in may case, I only obtain a permutation, and I´m not intererest in know what permutation was applied. I like

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for the comment. `Dispatch` added. But it should still be a factor of log(length_of_list) more slowly than yours (and thank you very much! I am learning your nice method, which should be useful in many cases).

Comment: @yi-wang reallly your answer does exactly what I wanted. I think that using s[a]=s[b], instead a rule, make it easy. But it´s very pretty :-) the solution